# Should JSX mode be react or react-native?

Tags: typescript, react-native

Basing this question on [this TypeScript official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html):

> The **react** mode will emit React.createElement, does not need to go
> through a JSX transformation before use, and the output will have a
> .js file extension.
>
> The **react-native** mode is the equivalent of
> preserve in that it keeps all JSX, but the output will instead have a
> .js file extension.

But, all the tutorials I've seen have it react mode:

```
"jsx": "react"
```

While this works perfectly, and I don't even see a warning, I'd like to understand how/why is it that React Native compiles the `TSX` and is able to load them without any problem.

Basically:

1. Why create the `react-native` mode, when React Native supports `react` mode?
2. Would there be any performance reason to use one over the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before React Native came along, the world was nice and clean:

```
| File Extension |  Has JSX Syntax  |  Has Type Annotations  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   .tsx         |       Yes        |          Yes           |
|   .ts          |       No         |          Yes           |
|   .jsx         |       Yes        |          No            |
|   .js          |       No         |          No            |
```

When TypeScript saw a `.tsx` file, it could decide whether to emit `.jsx` files (under `jsx: preserve`) or `.js` files (under `jsx: react`). It wasn't possible to emit `.js` files with JSX syntax in them (because *JSX isn't legal JavaScript syntax*).

Then React Native said "We'll have JSX syntax in .js files!", which is weird because it's illegal, but anyway. So if you're writing React Native code in TypeScript, you sometimes want TS to take `.tsx` input files and produce `.js` files that still have JSX syntax in them. Thus the JSX mode `react-native` was born.

Comment: Gotta love the JavaScript spaghetti world (coming from c#)... While this does answer the first question, can you explain whether there'll be any performance hit using `react` mode in `react-native`?